# calling another project class from another android?

Tags: android, class

I want to call a class of another project. I added it in the build path and also declared that class in the manifest file but when I call it gives me a `no class found` error.  I am calling it from intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), org.coolreader.CoolReader.class);
intent.putExtra("path", adapter.getItem(position).getPath());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Did you find answers useful???

Comment: yes i found the ans.answers were useful :) thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch `CoolReader` from your program than look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574735/904049):

```
Intent coolReaderIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.coolreader.CoolReader");
coolReaderIntent.putExtra("path", adapter.getItem(position).getPath());
startActivity(coolReaderIntent);
```

Of course, `CoolReader` (program) should be installed on the device.